# Expected value of absolute difference of independent discrete RVs

Tags: random-variables, expected-value, uniform-distribution

Let two random variables $X,Y$ be iid. on $\mathsf{U}_{\{1,\ldots,n\}}$.
I am trying to find the expected value of $Z = |X-Y|$.
This is my approach so far but I think there's something wrong:

Define $h(X,Y) = |X-Y|$. Then we have
$$
\DeclareMathOperator{\EV}{\mathbb{E}}
  \begin{align*}
    \EV[Z] &= \EV[h(X,Y)] \\
    &= \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n h(x_i, y_j) P(X = x_i, Y = y_j) \\
    &= \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n |x_i - y_j| P(X = x_1)P(Y = y_1) \\
    &= \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n \frac{|x_i - y_j|}{n^2} \\
    &= \frac{1}{n^2} \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n |x_i - y_j|
  \end{align*}
$$

So we need to evaluate $\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n |x_i - y_j|$, where $x_i = i, y_j = j$. Thus, we would get something like this
$$
  \begin{align*}
    &|x_1 - y_1| + |x_1 - y_2| + \ldots + |x_1 - y_n| \\
    +\,\, &|x_2 - y_1| + |x_2 - y_2| + \ldots + |x_2 - y_n| \\
    +\,\, & \ldots \\
  \end{align*}
$$
which should give
$$
  1 + 2 + \ldots + (n-1) \\
  1 + 2 + \ldots + (n-2) \\
  \vdots \\
$$
Hence the double sum should be equal to
$$
  \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} k(n-k) = \frac{n^3-n}{6}
$$
Which implies
$$
  \EV[Z] = \frac{n^2-1}{6n}
$$

But I have the feeling this somehow can't be correct. Too hacky if I compare it to the result of the continuous case. But perhaps the discrete case just happens to involve this ugly sum.

Thanks for any help :)